# Force Logout Script

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am not the greatest VB programmer so I could use a hand.
I am trying to write a script to force log out employees in my access timecard if they fail to do so after 2359. The error that I keep getting:

> TimeclockF.cmdForce_Click -- item not found in this collection

I'm not sure what I messed up.

TimeclockF is my form

.cmdForce is the button to call the script.

```
Private Sub cmdForce_Click()
    ' Comments:
    ' Params  : Force check out on blank check out dates
    
    
    On Error GoTo PROC_ERR

Dim strSQL As String, db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset

If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to proceed? This will check all the visitors with no check out " & _
         "date!", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton2, "Are you Sure?") = vbNo Then Exit Sub

strSQL = "Select * from TimeTable Where TimeOut Is Null"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

If Not rs.EOF Then
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        rs.Edit
        rs!TImeOut = #11:59:00 PM#
        rs!ForceCheckOut = True
        rs.Update
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End If

Set db = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing

PROC_EXIT:
    Exit Sub

PROC_ERR:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, Me.Name & ".cmdForce_Click"
    Resume PROC_EXIT


End Sub
```

Comment: Comment out your error handler `On Error GoTo PROC_ERR` so you will see which line actually fails.

Comment: Most likely a spelling error in one of your field names.

Comment: Also, you don't need a recordset loop for updates like this - one UPDATE query would be much easier.

Comment: Yeah your right, I could just write a query. I was trying to be too fancy. Thanks!

Comment: Comment error handler or set a breakpoint and step debug.